# How to approach verifying thread-safety in container registrations

Tags: c#, simple-injector

In our project we use SimpleInjector and love it!
We wanted to add an extension to the container that after registration of services will verify registrations comply to the following thread-safety demands:

1. Every singleton registered should be annotated with self-made [ThreadSafe]
2. If a service is annotated with [ThreadSafe] its implementation type should also be registered with [ThreadSafe].

We verify this now by having a `ThreadSafetyVerifyingContainer` that wraps SimpleInjector's Container, which exposes similar registration methods that also keep track of data SimpleInjector doesn't provide by `GetCurrentRegistrations()` such as open-generic type registrations. This approach works, but has its limits (like trouble to support Func factories in conditional registrations) and we ask ourselves if there's a way to hook into the verification process in order to inject our thread-safety verifications while calling `Verify` on the container. Here is our current code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A wrapper around C that exposes the subset of <see cref="Container"/> API required for registration at the moment,
/// that during <see cref="Verify"/> it verifies registrations using the underline container and additionally 
/// verifies that current registrations conform to thread-safety expectations.
/// </summary>
public class ThreadSafetyVerifyingContainer
{
    public ThreadSafetyVerifyingContainer()
    {
        _underlineContainer = new Container();
        _openGenericExplicitRegistrations = new List<RegistrationDescription>();
        _threadSafetyExternalAnnotations = new HashSet<Type>();
        MarkWellKnownExternalThreadSafeTypes();
    }

    public ContainerOptions Options => _underlineContainer.Options;

    public Container Verify(VerificationOption options = VerificationOption.VerifyAndDiagnose)
    {
        _underlineContainer.Verify(options);
        VerifyThreadSafety();

        return _underlineContainer;
    }

    // Marks a type as thread-safe as a replacement to applying <see cref="ThreadSafeAttribute"/> to a type.
    // Should be applied to external types not defined in the application, since <see cref="ThreadSafeAttribute"/> 
    // exists also for documentation purposes to let developers know some types are expected to be thread safe. 
    public void MarkExternalTypeAsThreadSafe(Type externalType)
    {
        _threadSafetyExternalAnnotations.Add(externalType);
    }

    private void VerifyThreadSafety()
    {
        var allRegistrationsDescriptions = _underlineContainer
            .GetCurrentRegistrations()
            .Select(RegistrationDescription.FromInstanceProducer)
            .Concat(_openGenericExplicitRegistrations)
            .ToArray();

        var invalidSingletonRegistrations = allRegistrationsDescriptions
            .Where(registration =>
                registration.Lifestyle == Lifestyle.Singleton &&
                !IsImplementationTypeMarkedAsThreadSafe(registration))
            .Select(registration =>
                $"The type {registration.ImplementationType} is registered as singleton but isn't marked as thread-safe using {nameof(ThreadSafeAttribute)}");

        var invalidThreadSafeServiceRegistrations = allRegistrationsDescriptions
            .Where(registration =>
                IsTypeMarkedAsThreadSafe(registration.ServiceType) &&
                !IsImplementationTypeMarkedAsThreadSafe(registration))
            .Select(registration =>
                $"The type {registration.ImplementationType} isn't marked as thread-safe using {nameof(ThreadSafeAttribute)} and is registered as implementation of {registration.ServiceType} which is marked as thread-safe");

        var violations = invalidSingletonRegistrations.Concat(invalidThreadSafeServiceRegistrations).ToArray();

        if (violations.Length > 0)
        {
            string errorMessage =
                $"The container has thread-safety violating registrations:{Environment.NewLine}{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, violations)}";
            throw new ThreadSafetyViolationException(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    private void MarkWellKnownExternalThreadSafeTypes()
    {
        MarkExternalTypeAsThreadSafe(typeof(Container)); // SimpleInjector's Container is registered as singleton and is thread safe, ignore it
        MarkExternalTypeAsThreadSafe(typeof(IEnumerable<>)); // Collections are IEnumerable<> implementations registered by the container as singletons, ignore them
    }

    private bool IsImplementationTypeMarkedAsThreadSafe(RegistrationDescription registration)
    {
        return IsTypeMarkedAsThreadSafe(registration.ImplementationType);
    }

    private bool IsTypeMarkedAsThreadSafe(Type type)
    {
        return 
            type.GetCustomAttribute<ThreadSafeAttribute>() != null || 
            _threadSafetyExternalAnnotations.Contains(type) || 
            _threadSafetyExternalAnnotations.Any(threadSafeType => threadSafeType.IsGenericTypeDefinition && type.IsGenericOf(threadSafeType));
    }

    private readonly HashSet<Type> _threadSafetyExternalAnnotations; 
    #endregion

    public void Register<TService, TImplementation>(Lifestyle lifestyle)
        where TService : class where TImplementation : class, TService
    {
        _underlineContainer.Register<TService, TImplementation>(lifestyle);
    }

    public void Register(Type openGenericServiceType, Assembly assembly, Lifestyle lifestyle)
    {
        _underlineContainer.Register(openGenericServiceType, new [] { assembly }, lifestyle);
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton<TService, TImplementation>()
        where TImplementation : class, TService
        where TService : class
    {
        _underlineContainer.RegisterSingleton<TService, TImplementation>();
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton<TConcrete>()
        where TConcrete :  class
    {
        _underlineContainer.RegisterSingleton<TConcrete>();
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton<TService>(TService instance) where TService : class
    {
        _underlineContainer.RegisterSingleton(instance);
    }

    public void RegisterScoped<TService, TImplementation>()
        where TImplementation : class, TService
        where TService : class
    {
        _underlineContainer.Register<TService, TImplementation>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }

    public void RegisterTransient<TService, TImplementation>()
        where TService : class where TImplementation : class, TService
    {
        _underlineContainer.Register<TService, TImplementation>();
    }

    public void RegisterTransient<TImplementation>()
        where TImplementation : class
    {
        _underlineContainer.Register<TImplementation>();
    }

    public void RegisterTransient<TService>(Func<TService> instanceCreator)
        where TService : class
    {
        _underlineContainer.Register(instanceCreator);
    }

    public void RegisterCollectionScoped<TService>(IEnumerable<Type> concreteTypes)
        where TService : class
    {
        _underlineContainer.RegisterCollection<TService>(concreteTypes.Select(type => Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(type, _underlineContainer)));
    }

    public void Register(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, Lifestyle lifestyle)
    {
        _underlineContainer.Register(serviceType, implementationType, lifestyle);
        RecordIfExplicitOpenGenericRegistration(serviceType, implementationType, lifestyle);
    }

    public void RegisterConditional(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, Lifestyle lifestyle, Predicate<PredicateContext> predicate)
    {
        _underlineContainer.RegisterConditional(serviceType, implementationType, lifestyle, predicate);
        RecordIfExplicitOpenGenericRegistration(serviceType, implementationType, lifestyle);
    }

    public void RegisterImplementationByConsumerContext(Type notGenericServiceType, Type openGenericImplementationType, Lifestyle lifestyle)
    {
        Guard.CheckNullArgument(notGenericServiceType, nameof(notGenericServiceType));
        Guard.CheckNullArgument(openGenericImplementationType, nameof(openGenericImplementationType));
        Guard.CheckArgument(notGenericServiceType.IsGenericType, nameof(notGenericServiceType), $"Type {notGenericServiceType} shouldn't be a generic type but it is");
        Guard.CheckArgument(!openGenericImplementationType.ContainsGenericParameters, nameof(openGenericImplementationType), $"Type {openGenericImplementationType} isn't an open-generic type");
        Guard.CheckArgument(openGenericImplementationType.GetGenericArguments().Length != 1, nameof(openGenericImplementationType), $"Type {openGenericImplementationType} is open-generic but has more than 1 generic parameter");

        _underlineContainer.RegisterConditional(
            notGenericServiceType,
            context => openGenericImplementationType.MakeGenericType(context.Consumer.ImplementationType),
            lifestyle,
            context => true);
        RecordIfExplicitOpenGenericRegistration(notGenericServiceType, openGenericImplementationType, lifestyle);
    }

    private void RecordIfExplicitOpenGenericRegistration(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, Lifestyle lifestyle)
    {
        if (implementationType.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            _openGenericExplicitRegistrations.Add(new RegistrationDescription(serviceType, implementationType, lifestyle));
        }
    }

    private readonly List<RegistrationDescription> _openGenericExplicitRegistrations;

    [DebuggerDisplay("{ServiceType.Name} -> {ImplementationType.Name} with {Lifestyle.Name} life style")]
    private class RegistrationDescription
    {
        public RegistrationDescription(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, Lifestyle lifestyle)
        {
            ServiceType = serviceType;
            ImplementationType = implementationType;
            Lifestyle = lifestyle;
        }

        public static RegistrationDescription FromInstanceProducer(InstanceProducer instanceProducer)
        {
            return new RegistrationDescription(
                instanceProducer.ServiceType,
                instanceProducer.Registration.ImplementationType,
                instanceProducer.Registration.Lifestyle);
        }

        public Type ServiceType { get; }
        public Type ImplementationType { get; }
        public Lifestyle Lifestyle { get; }
    }

    private readonly Container _underlineContainer;
}
```

Comment: I played with the ExpressionBuild and ExpressionBuilding events and noticed it covers all registrations that are participating in the built-in verification process, so they could be used to fill a list of thread-safety violations (or any other service-implementation-lifestyle custom rule violation) to raise an exception about them at the end of the built-in verification process.

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no way to hook onto the `Verify` or diagnosis. although there are several ways to get lots of information back from Simple Injector to do analysis yourself. For instance, there is a `Container.GetCurrentRegistrations` method that gets a list of known `InstanceProducer` instances. There is an `InstanceProducer.GetKnownRelationships` method that allows iterating through the object graph recursively (the diagnostic services use this method and the `KnownRelationship` instances extensively).

In your case however, you might also look at a different approach, which is overriding the `ILifestyleSelectionBehavior`. With a custom lifestyle selection behavior you can influence the lifestyle that will be chosen by Simple Injector when no explicit lifestyle is chosen. By default, Simple Injector will give you a transient lifestyle. In your case, the custom behavior would look as follows:

```
class ThreadSafeAsSingletonLifestyleSelectionBehavior : ILifestyleSelectionBehavior {
    public Lifestyle SelectLifestyle(Type serviceType, Type implementationType) {
        var sa = serviceType.GetCustomAttribute<ThreadSafeAttribute>();
        var ia = implementationType.GetCustomAttribute<ThreadSafeAttribute>();
        if (sa != null && ia == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "If a service is annotated with [ThreadSafe] its implementation "+
            "type should also be registered with [ThreadSafe].");

        return ia == null ? Lifestyle.Transient : Lifestyle.Singleton;
    }
}
```

You can register you custom behavior as follows:

```
container.Options.LifestyleSelectionBehavior =
    new ThreadSafeAsSingletonLifestyleSelectionBehavior();
```

What this allows is having all implementations that are marked with `[ThreadSafe]` to be automatically registered as singleton and it forces implementations to have a `[ThreadSafe]` attribute in case their service types do.

This means that everytime you don't explicitly register a type with a lifestyle, the lifestyle selection behavior kicks in. Example:

```
container.Register<IThreadSafeService, ThreadSafeImplementation>();
```

However, do note that this registration will still get a transient lifestyle:

```
container.Register<IThreadSafeService, ThreadSafeImplementation>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```